# Plain-text tag list?

Tags: posts, tags

I'm looking for a way to display a plain-text list of tags to use as classes on my post elements, I've been trying

```
$tags = get_tags();
$tag_list = "";
foreach($tags as $tag){
    $tag_list .= $tag->name . " ";
}
echo "<li class=\"$tag_list\">";
```

in the loop but it seems to output all the tags instead of just the current post's tags, so if I have tags `x`, `y`, and `z`, and I'm viewing a post with tag `x` I still get `<li class="x y z">` anybody have any ideas as to how to show a plain-text list of tags or what I'm doing wrong?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can play with arguments to only fetch what you need and get rid of loop:

```
$classes = implode(' ', wp_get_post_tags( get_the_ID(), array('fields' => 'names') ) );
```

Comment: Gotta love one-liners... I've supplied an answer below for doing this with custom taxonomies...

Answer (score 1):

Use [**wp_get_post_tags**](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_get_post_tags) instead:

```
$tags = wp_get_post_tags($post->ID);
$tag_list = "";
foreach($tags as $tag){
    $tag_list .= $tag->name . " ";
}
echo "<li class=\"$tag_list\">";
```

Comment: This works, but I gotta give props to the one-liner...

Answer (score 1):

Rarst got me off to a good start, but if you want to do this with a custom taxonomy you should use

`$classes = implode(' ', wp_get_object_terms($post->ID, 'custom_post_type', array('fields'=>'names')) );`